# Ensure TextField actually includes text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

So while carrying out functional tests on my app prior to submission for external testing, I've found that I can satisfy my current code by placing a number of spaces in a text field rather than actual text.

The following code works fine if the keyboard is not touched, but doesn't work if I hit the space bar a couple of times:

```
if (nameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
```

I have tried the following code also, but get the same result:

```
if (nameTextField.text?.count)! < 1 {
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always remove leading and trailing whitespace from user entered values when appropriate.

```
let cleanedText = nameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
if cleanedText.isEmpty {
    // empty or just spaces
} else {
    // Use cleanedText as needed
}
```

Note that it is safe to force-unwrap `UITextField text` since it is documented to never return `nil`.

Comment: Just a note that he'll probably want to use the real text in the `else`. I'll be on my way then. _runs away_

Comment: @RakeshaShastri That's up to the individual developer to decide but in most cases you don't want to keep any inadvertent whitespace.

Comment: @rmaddy I was thinking like this. If the user was entering "Hello. How are you?" and the dev wants to check if the textField does not contain only white spaces. Then he'd just do trimming for checking the empty condition and use the original string for processing.